# unable to wrap my HTMLTableRowElement into an object in plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

this is my 
stockDetail.js

```
import CurrencyPair from './CurrencyPair';
class StockData {
  constructor() {
    this.currencyPair = []
  }
  print (currencyData) {
    console.log(currencyData,this.currencyPair)
    if (this.currencyPair.length == 0 || this.currencyPair.forEach(pair => {
      console.log('pair is',pair.name,'newName is',currencyData.name)
      console.log('boolean is',pair.name !== currencyData.name)
      })) {
      console.log("inside this")
      this.currencyPair.push(currencyData)
      var row = { 
           <tr>
                <td>${currencyData.name}</td> 
                <td>${currencyData.bestBid}</td>
                <td>${currencyData.bestAsk}</td>
                <td>${currencyData.openBid}</td>
                <td>${currencyData.openAsk}</td>
           </tr>
       }
      return row          
  }
}
}
module.exports = StockData
```

my index.js

```
 function recieve() {
      client.subscribe('blah/blah', function (response) {
        if (response.body) {
        console.log(typeof(stockData.print(JSON.parse(response.body))))
          renderingElement.appendChild(stockData.print(JSON.parse(response.body)))
          console.log('render', renderingElement.innerHTML)
        }
      })
}
```

I need to append a table row to my renderElement which is a tbody,
 but it kind of takes a NodeElement some HTMLElementWrapped in an object, 
 so i need to wrap my ....  into an object.

Comment: That's not plain JS, react?

Comment: @Teemu that is plain JS and not react.

Comment: `var row = {<td>...}` is definitely not plain JS, you've a framework under the hood.

Comment: @Teemu exactly, thats not working but i need something like that

Comment: Ah, OK. You've to create a row element: `document.createElement('tr')`, then using the same method, create `td` elements, add content to `td`s, and [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) them to the newly-created row, that way you'll have a "row object".

Comment: @Teemu i dont want so many dom manipulations that's why i am trying to keep it to the minimum by not creatingElements tons of times. I am not quite sure but can i reduce it to an object? using reduce, i cant of have an idea, but not sure how to implement that.

Comment: There won't be any DOM manipulation before you append the row object to an existing tbody, everything is executed in JS until the final append. That's the only way to get a real row object. You can play with HTML strings, but they're not as fast as using objects, nevertheless object creation might take more code.